# Null reference exception while using Count

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, count

I have a method to get count of the items, but got stucked with a silly exception:

```
 internal static bool IsCompanyInList(int companyId, int favoritecompanyId)
        {
            var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies.Count(c => c.CompanyId == companyId && c.FavouriteCompanyId == favoritecompanyId); // getting exception here
            if ( result >0)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Also, one more clue, my table is empty . There is no row at all. How to handle this situation.
I have also tried Where clause. See below:

```
 var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies.Where(criteria_here);
```

Comment: Stick the debugger on the line and see what is null - my guess would be the _context variable.

Comment: Where do you define your _context? It's a static method referring to a instance member?

Comment: @Paddy : Thanks , your answer worked. Please post it as answer so that i can accept it. Actually the issue was that my context was static member and i wall creating its instance inside the non-static constructor. Thanks.....

Comment: @Walther : Your guess was also correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FavouriteCompanies is null. You can do something like that:

```
internal static bool IsCompanyInList(int companyId, int favoritecompanyId)
            {
                var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies;
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    return result.Any(c => c.CompanyId == companyId && c.FavouriteCompanyId == favoritecompanyId);
                } 

                return false;
            }
```

In that solution `if (result>0)` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would help if you could include the stack, but I presume that the FavouriteCompanies collection has a null in it (or perhaps the _context variable is null - if you chain lots of methods together with a "." you get a train-wreck where it is hard to tell what is null). You could get round this defensively by removing the nulls :

```
var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies.Where( c => c != null ).Count(...)
```

although to be honest it would be much better to find out where a null has been inserted into FavourieCompanies and stop it there.

Answer (score 1):

The error could be anywhere you attempt to access a member.

```
var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies.Count(c => c.CompanyId == companyId && c.FavouriteCompanyId == favoritecompanyId);
```

is _context null?
is _context.FavoriteCompanies null?
does FavoriteCompanies contain a record in which CompanyId or FavouriteCompanyId is null?

Since this is Linq2Sql, you can ask c.FavouriteCompanyId.Isnull() within the count clause before accessing the member itself.

Answer (score 1):

For me, one of **string (or nullable column)** value was null.

```
        var result = _context.FavouriteCompanies.Count(c => c.CompanyId != null && c.CompanyId == companyId && c.FavouriteCompanyId != null && c.FavouriteCompanyId == favoritecompanyId);
```